# Get response from the request in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

is there a way i can return a response from my parse method?

I tried this:

```
yield {
    'content': scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page),
}
```

but the response is:

```
'content': <GET https://example.com>
```

I expect the result would be like this:

```
'content': 'some text'
```

as the parse_page() method is parsing from some css selector.

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

It is object:

```py
scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)
```

Parameter body, this is what you need:

```py
response = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)
content = response.body
yield {
    'content': content,
}
```

Comment: It returned 'content': b' ' instead. I tried yield and return in parse_page method but it resulting the same. Sorry i really new in python.